# How to find duplicate time entry and duplicate time duration - SQL

Tags: sql, time, duration

Could any one help me for the below request

I have list of time entries with "Start Time" and "End Time".
But in some of the occasions, the entry has the same "End Time" and some of the occasions, the entry fall in to the same time entry duration.

I need the duration from the time entries but as duration which needs to reflect without duplicate time entry duration. Meaning I need one time duration even though there are many entry with different start time and end time.

Please see as below.

**Scenario 1:**

```
ID  Log No   Start time     End time
5   1001    4/6/2014 6:34   4/6/2014 7:47
5   1001    4/6/2014 0:34   4/6/2014 0:47
5   1002    4/6/2014 0:09   4/6/2014 0:47
5   1000    4/5/2014 23:36  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1000    4/5/2014 23:16  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1008    4/5/2014 22:50  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1006    4/5/2014 22:41  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1010    4/5/2014 22:26  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1008    4/5/2014 22:50  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1006    4/5/2014 22:41  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1008    4/5/2014 22:26  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1003    4/5/2014 22:13  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1005    4/5/2014 22:01  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1010    4/5/2014 21:48  4/6/2014 0:47
5   1010    4/5/2014 17:48  4/5/2014 21:47
```

**Final Result:** (duration of these time entry as they are fall in same period). Log No can be ignored in the result / output - basically Log no doesn't matter. It is the duration what I am trying to get.

```
5   1001    4/6/2014 6:34   4/6/2014 7:47   1.22
5   1010    4/5/2014 21:48  4/6/2014 0:47   2.97
5   1010    4/5/2014 17:48  4/5/2014 21:47  3.97
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
5   1002    4/4/2014 12:38  4/4/2014 15:45
5   1002    4/4/2014 7:47   4/4/2014 8:45
5   1000    4/4/2014 7:17   4/4/2014 7:20
5   1008    4/4/2014 7:15   4/4/2014 7:45
5   1003    4/4/2014 7:08   4/4/2014 7:28
5   1005    4/4/2014 7:05   4/4/2014 10:08
5   1005    4/4/2014 5:08   4/4/2014 8:06
```

**Final Result:**

```
5   1002    4/4/2014 12:38  4/4/2014 15:45  3.12
5   1005    4/4/2014 7:05   4/4/2014 10:08  3.06
5   1005    4/4/2014 5:08   4/4/2014 8:06   2.98
```

Please note, both scenario is possible in one set of data.
Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is "merge overlapping intervals". If you search Google with that, you will find a plethora of answers.

That said, you can do the following, assuming the list of entries are in array `a` and the resultant list is in array `b` both having length >= `n` which happens to be the number of entries in `a`:

Pseudocode

```
Sort a by start asc
i=0
r=0
while i<n
    j = i+1
    while j <n
        if a(j).start <= a(i).end
            a(i).end = max(a(i).end, a(j).end)
            ++j
        else
            exit while
        endif
    endwhile
    b(r)=a(i)
    ++r
    i=j
endwhile
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this somewhere close? I simplified a bit and removed id from the expression since all rows had the same value:

`with t (log_no, start, end) as (
values
(1001    ,timestamp('2014-04-06-06.34.00')
            ,  timestamp('2014-04-06-07.47.00')),
(1001    ,'2014-04-06-00.34.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1002    ,'2014-04-06-00.09.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1000    ,'2014-04-05-23.36.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1000    ,'2014-04-05-23.16.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1008    ,'2014-04-05-22.50.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1006    ,'2014-04-05-22.41.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1010    ,'2014-04-05-22.26.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1008    ,'2014-04-05-22.50.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1006    ,'2014-04-05-22.41.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1008    ,'2014-04-05-22.26.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1003    ,'2014-04-05-22.13.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1005    ,'2014-04-05-22.01.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1010    ,'2014-04-05-21.48.00',  '2014-04-06-00.47.00'),
(1010    ,'2014-04-05-17.48.00',  '2014-04-05-21.47.00')
)
select log_no, min(start), end
from (
    select log_no, start, min(t1.end) end
    from t t1
    where not exists (
        select 1 from t t2
        where t1.end <= t2.start and t1.end > t2.end
          and t1.log_no = t2.log_no
          and not (t1.start,t1.end) = (t2.start,t2.end)
    )
    group by log_no, start
) as u
group by u.log_no, end`